# How can I find the strongest postcondition for those two Hoare triples?

Tags: logic, hoare-logic

I'm trying to solve an exercise in which I have to find the strongest post-condition of the two Hoare triples.

\begin{gather*}
    (| a=9 |)\ a=2; b=a+1; a=b*b;\ (| ?? |)\\
    (| i=-j |)\ i=i+1; j=j-1;\ (| ?? |)
\end{gather*}
For the first one, I found post condition as  $a > b$. For the second one, I found $j = |i|$. However, it seems like they are not the strongest. What are the strongest postconditions for those triples and why?

Comment: Did you check the definition of strongest postcondition? Note that $j=|i|$ isn't even a postcondition (let alone a strongest one): consider running the code fragment starting with $i=1$, $j=-1$.

Comment: There is no single strongest post-condition: if $P$ is a strongest post-condition, then so is e.g. $P \wedge 2=2$. More importantly, the answer to your question depends on the *exact* nature of the programming language that you use. For example: can variables be aliased?

Comment: I am really confused. I am looking at the predicate transformer semantics by Dijkstra, but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: and also.. Can someone explain me why a > b is not a strongest postcondition for the first one.